# Laravel: Ordering posts by category in numerical order

Tags: laravel

In my application I want to order my posts by category in numerical order.
So I guess I need a mapping table like this:

```
category_id | post_id | sort_order
```

then setting up a kind of "Order model" with specific methods that handle it all and use this model as a relationship with the Post model.

But before I start on this project I'd like to know if there is not a Laravel package out there that does the job or another solution that I might have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, if I understand your need correctly, but I guess your posts are stored in a DB.
Then you can simply directly get the posts from DB ordered:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
            ->orderBy('category_id ', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('post_id', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

See the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

I don't think, you need a Order model or something similar to realize this.

Comment: Your solution could work if the posts belonged to only one category, but in my Post model a post can actually belong to several categories hence the Order model...

Comment: can you tell us, how your db structure looks like?

Comment: The structure consists of 2 basic tables for the posts and categories (id, name, created_at...) plus a pivot table for the belongsToMany relationship.